# Como fazer threads para servidor em Python?

Tags: python, thread, socket

Olá sou iniciante em Python e estou criando um servidor simples mas não consigo criar threads independentes. Quando o cliente se conecta no servidor ele chama a função worker que aguarda uma mensagem do cliente para enviar uma resposta. Acontece que só é executada uma conexão de cada vez e na ordem de conexão, deixando os outros clientes que já enviaram a mensagem esperando.

```
while True:
    conn, address = ss.accept()
    print('DEBUG: Connected by ',  address)
    obj = threading.Thread(target = ServerWorker.worker(conn))
    obj.start()
```

Função worker:

```
def worker(conn):
    print('Running...')
    _in = conn.recv(1024)
    msg = _in.decode(encoding = 'utf-8')
    print('DEBUG: Processing ', msg, '...')
    msg = 'ECHO: ' + msg
    _out = conn.sendall(bytes(msg,encoding = 'utf-8'))
    conn.close()
```

Tentei apenas chamar outro script .py ao invés da thread mas não consegui passar o objeto conn como argumento. Por favor me ajudem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Da forma que você está fazendo, está chamando a função `ServerWorker.worker()` primeiro e depois tentando iniciar a thread com o resultado dessa função (que no caso é `None` já que ela não retorna nada). Os parênteses forçam a chamada da função para que seja extraído seu resultado, antes de iniciar a thread. Seu código atual é equivalente a isso:

```
resultado = ServerWorker.worker(conn)
obj = threading.Thread(target = resultado)
```

Na verdade, quem vai chamar a função é o módulo `threading` do python e não o seu código. Você deve passar a função sem chamá-la você mesmo, ou seja, não coloque os parênteses `()` depois do nome da função, assim estará passando a função em si e não o resultado dela.

Os parâmetros que você quer passar para a função `target` devem ser passados em `args` e `kwargs`, para que o módulo `threading` possa depois passá-los para a sua função quando for a hora, como diz na [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread):

```
obj = threading.Thread(target=ServerWorker.worker, args=[conn])
```

Veja que deve ser passado um iterável com os parâmetros posicionais, no exemplo acima foi a lista `[]`.

Comment: Entendi. Realmente a thread não era criada até que a função executasse. Muito obrigado!

Comment: @WandersonLima que bom que ajudou! se a minha resposta atendeu, considere marcá-la como aceita, para fechar a pergunta.